# Post request Json, Code is done but dont work

Tags: java, json

I want to create a POST-Request with the key "json" and use the command "getorders" to get all orders.

With my Code I get the return:

```
{
"getorders"
}
POST Response Code : 200
POST Response Message : OK
```

What I am doing wrong? Is my command false? 
First i create the connection to the  URL, then I create the request. After that I wrote a responder. So the "syntax" should be good, the only thing I could think of is the command.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class JSONTester {

    private static String dirPath = ;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File file = new File(dirPath + "//array_complex.json");
        try {
            final String POST_PARAMS = "{\n" + "\"getorders\" \r\n" + "\n}";
            System.out.println(POST_PARAMS);
            URL obj = new URL();
            HttpURLConnection postConnection = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
            postConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            postConnection.setRequestProperty("connection", "Keep-Alive");
            postConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            java.io.OutputStream os = postConnection.getOutputStream();
            os.write(POST_PARAMS.getBytes());
            os.flush();
            os.close();
            int responseCode = postConnection.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("POST Response Code :  " + responseCode);
            System.out.println("POST Response Message : " + postConnection.getResponseMessage());
            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) { //success
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(postConnection.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();
                // print result
                System.out.println(response.toString());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you're receiving a 200 status code, the only thing that seems odd is that it shows that `getorders` value in the response. Do you own the API? Is that an expected response for your request?

Comment: I dont own the API but i have a command list. Like i answered the answer below, I forgot to add the parameter "bid". "bid" need to get added by all requests. -> "bid" returns nothing, but as i said, it needs to get added by all requests (says the command list). Also there is a command "getorder" which return the details of the order.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a wrong assumption:

```
    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) { //success
```

This is not correct, the responseCode is 200 while HTTP_CREATED is 201. If you change it to

```
    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { //success
```

your code will enter the if block and read the inputStream. After running your code with HTTP_OK I get:

```
POST Response Code :  200
POST Response Message : OK
{"error":true,"errortext":"field \u00b4json\u00b4 not found in post"}
```

Maybe you should read the API on how to call this service, what parameters are required, etc.

Update:

I tried with different json messages and I understood what you meant by 'key "json" and command "getorders" so I came up with the following:

```
final String POST_PARAMS = "json={\n" + "\"key\":\"getorders\" \r\n" + "\n}";
```

The above returns:

```
POST Response Code :  200
POST Response Message : OK
{"error":true,"errortext":"no userid found"}
```

So what is left, is you add the json fields that are missing, or read the API of this service and add the fields and values to the POST_PARAMS.

Update 2:

after your comment I managed to get an order using the following

```
 final String POST_PARAMS = "json={\"bid\":\"bid\", \"getorder\":\"1\"}";
```

I tried to set bid using userId/userID/userid but did not work, I am not sure if bid:bid is correct but it works and I think you get the point from now on.

Result:

```
POST Response Code :  200
POST Response Message : OK
{"Bestellnummer":"1","Besteller":"8195529","Zeit":"2019-09-27 15:50:07","Artikel":[{"Artikelnummer":"76194","Anzahl":"1","Preis":"2.968"},{"Artikelnummer":"61681","Anzahl":"1","Preis":"7.147"},{"Artikelnummer":"111756","Anzahl":"1","Preis":"9.29"},{"Artikelnummer":"14227","Anzahl":"1","Preis":"0"}]}
```

Comment: Yeah my mistake, i forgot to add the parameter "bid". "bid" need to get added by all requests. Its my userID.  -> "bid" return nothing, but as i said, it needs to get added by all requests. 

Also there is a command "getorder" which return the details of the order. 

When i have the userid 347 and use the command getorder i should get all orders, or I am wrong?

Comment: I updated my answer. Keep in mind that in json you dont need to set new lines. So this json is still valid json={"bid":"bid", "getorder":"1"}